# Algorithm for predicting outcome based on parameters

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, statistics

I've never done anything with statistics, so I'm unsure of how to start with this problem that I need to solve for some software that I'm working on.

Basically, there are three parameters

1. An integer parameter (A) that can be a range of (for the sake of argument) 1-10
2. A Boolean parameter (B) that if present weights the value of A.
3. An integer parameter (C) that can be a range of 1-100.

There is one outcome: An integer (D) that can be of the range -1, 0, 1.

For each value of C, there will be one value of A, B, and D. C is a preexisting condition. A, and B are parameters. D is the outcome, which may be subjective.

```
+---+----+---+----+
| C | A  | B | D  |
+---+----+---+----+
| 1 |  3 | 0 | -1 |
| 1 |  3 | 1 | -1 |
| 1 |  5 | 0 |  0 |
| 1 |  5 | 0 |  0 |
| 1 | 10 | 0 |  1 |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |  1 |
| 2 |  3 | 0 | -1 |
| 2 |  3 | 1 |  0 |
| 2 |  4 | 0 |  0 |
| 2 |  4 | 1 |  0 |
+---+----+---+----+
```

What I'm looking for, is given C, A, B, how can I make a prediction of what D will be. In this case, I will have historical data of all four values to go from. C won't necessarily be linear as in my example.

Comment: This seems like a good fit for an Adaptive Logic Network.

Comment: My statistics may be a little rusty, but I'm not sure what D is supposed to represent.  Looks like it could be a sort of [coefficient of determinination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: On a side note, with 100 possible values for C * 2 possible values for B * 10 possible values for A, you could code this up as a lookup table pretty easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) problem.

It seems to be a **classification** task i.e. the output variable `D` takes class labels (the other group is the **regression** task).

There are [a lot of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Classification_algorithms) for classification and you should probably start with something simple e.g. [logistic regression](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html).

If I misunderstood the example and yours is a [symbolic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Classification_algorithms) task, a good approach is genetic programming (you have to specify a set of primitive and new equations are then formed by recombining previous equations).

Comment: You've given me enough to start investigating. I'm in completely new territory, so I didn't even know the right terminology. Thank you very much!